# Adding Armadillo C++ to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, armadillo

I am trying to run the example that comes with the library but I have this error
fatal error C1189: #error :  "*** Need a newer compiler ***"

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and did the following
1- I added the include folder from the library to VS2010 includes 
   **Project >> Properties >> VS++ Directories >> Include Diretories** 
   I can see the dependencies files in External Dependencies Folder
2 - I have uncommented the bellow lines in "include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp" as reqested in Armdaillo Readme.txt

```
  #define ARMA_USE_LAPACK
  #define ARMA_USE_BLAS
  #define ARMA_USE_ARPACK
  #define ARMA_USE_SUPERLU
```

3- I added the libraries to the linker 
 **Project >> Properties >> Linker >> Input >> Additional dependencies :

lapack_win64_MT.lib
blas_win64_MT.lib

I hope I made it clear, Thanks

Comment: Either use a newer compiler (Get community edition of VS 2015 or something.) Or, use an older version of the Armadillo library which don't need a "newer compiler". That's what the error message says isn't it?

Comment: I checked the readme txt they didnt mention a specific version, unless i missed it

Comment: So which version of the library do you use?

Comment: I think it's 7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 8 of Readme.txt at https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/README.txt

> The MSCV project was tested on 64 bit Windows 7 with Visual C++ 2012.
>   You may need to make adaptations for 32 bit systems, later versions of
>   Windows and/or the compiler.  For example, you may have to enable or
>   disable ARMA_BLAS_LONG and ARMA_BLAS_UNDERSCORE macros in
>   "armadillo_bits/config.hpp".

Comment: My system is 64; i tried all the combination of disabling and enabling the above , still having same error

Comment: In this case better to contact the library maintainers themselves. See if they can help you.

Comment: See the github link

Comment: @nakiya: You linked a personal fork of armadillo which has not been updated in 3 years. The link to the README.txt of the official repository is [https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/README.txt]. There the information is found in section 8.